# String split for detection of a text page change from PDF

Tags: vb.net, pdf, split, itext

i'm trying to analyse a PDF document with itextsharp library...the final intent is read all text and split it for every line.

To do this, i use a split function of the readed text... i have complete text in a string var as this.

```
 Dim RigheTesto As String()
 RigheTesto = testoEstrapolato.Split({vbCrLf, vbCr, vbLf}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Split function work fine and i obtain a string array like "Data type: value", one array for every line from original file ...

... but when split encounter a change of page (in original PDF) **don't understand is a different line and it unites to previous** ...

Do you know how solve this problem please ?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: You need to add another delimiter to your list for whatever represents a page break. That might be `ControlChars.FormFeed` or it might be something else. You can analyse the text to find out, or maybe there's some standard for PDF files documented somewhere.

Comment: If that's not possible then I would think that iTextSharp would be able to give you pages individually, so you can then pick the lines out of each one and then combine the multiple lists of lines into one list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following shows how to extract text from a PDF file using NuGet package iTextSharp (it's been tested using v5.5.13.2).

**Download/install NuGet package** `iTextSharp`

**Create a class** (name: PdfPageInfo.vb)

```vb
Public Class PdfPageInfo
    Public Property PageNumber As Integer
    Public Property Lines As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
End Class
```

**Create a module** (name: HelperiTextSharp.vb)

```vb
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser

Module HelperiTextSharp
    Public Function ExtractText(filename As String) As List(Of PdfPageInfo)
        Dim pageInfoList As List(Of PdfPageInfo) = New List(Of PdfPageInfo)

        Using reader As PdfReader = New PdfReader(filename)
            For i As Integer = 1 To reader.NumberOfPages Step 1

                'create new instance
                Dim pageInfo As PdfPageInfo = New PdfPageInfo()

                'set value
                pageInfo.PageNumber = i

                'get text from PDF page
                Dim pageText As String = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i)

                'split on newline and set value
                pageInfo.Lines = pageText.Split(New String() {vbCrLf, vbCr, vbLf}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList()

                'add 
                pageInfoList.Add(pageInfo)
            Next
        End Using

        Return pageInfoList
    End Function
End Module
```

**Usage**:

```vb
Dim ofd As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()
ofd.Filter = "PDF files(*.pdf)|*.pdf"

If ofd.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
    Dim pdfPageInfoList As List(Of PdfPageInfo) = HelperiTextSharp.ExtractText(ofd.FileName)

    For Each pInfo As PdfPageInfo In pdfPageInfoList
        Debug.WriteLine("Page Number: " & pInfo.PageNumber.ToString())

        For i As Integer = 0 To pInfo.Lines.Count - 1 Step 1
            Debug.WriteLine("[" & i & "]: " & pInfo.Lines(i))
        Next

        Debug.WriteLine("---------------------------------" & vbCrLf)
    Next
End If
```

**Resource**:

- [How to read pdf file in C#? (Working example using iTextSharp)](https://qawithexperts.com/article/c-sharp/how-to-read-pdf-file-in-c-working-example-using-itextsharp/162)

Comment: Thanks to all fro your suggestions and thanks to the complete code sample in vb.net!!! Tomorrow i will apply this way to my code... i think it will run correctly and could solve my problem... so thanks for now... hear you later for final response.

Comment: Today i finish to test your code... it work perfectly !!! Thank you very very much, your help save me !